# Laravel authenticate users when their school is active

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication

We are making a laravel project that is for schools. We got a database for schools and inside it are the the users like teachers,staffs ect. My problem is how do I prevent the specific user from a specific school from logging in where their school status is marked = `0` or as inactive in our database?

Schools table

`+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name         | varchar(191)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| description  | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| logo         | varchar(191)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status       | int(11)          | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| updated_by   | varchar(191)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at   | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at   | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+`

Users table

`+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name              | varchar(191)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email             | varchar(191)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| password          | varchar(191)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| role              | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| school_id         | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| gender            | int(11)          | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| birthdate         | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address           | varchar(191)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| phone             | varchar(191)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| remember_token    | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+`

LoginController.php

````
class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    // protected $redirectTo = '/admin';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }



}```
````

User model

```
  public function schools()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\School', 'school_id');
    }
```

School model

```
 public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
```

My LoginController only uses the `AuthenticateUsers` function and I dont know a way how to override it or make a new function for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `LoginController` you can override the `authenticated` method, this function fires when the user has successfully signed in.

```
public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->schools()->status === 0) {
        Auth::logout($user);

        abort(403, 'Your school is not active.');
    }
}
```

1. I'm assuming here that you've setup relationships, if not then just select the school which the user is enrolled and check from that.
2. The reason why I suggest to override the `authenticated` method as opposed to other methods is that at this point you know the user has signed in correctly so it is the correct place to handle it as opposed to the `attemptLogin`.

Comment: Ive already set up the relationships in the model sir. Let me try this.

Comment: where should i insert this code sir? im getting an error of : `Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::authenticated() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in C:\Users\bustillo-ronald\Desktop\safe-web\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php on line 104`

Comment: I've put my models sir because im getting a new error of `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::school()` and some of the answers this is about my models. @Script47

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating a middleware to the login route, that will look after the user's status value for his school. If it's not valid, you should handle it for example, that you throw an exception back to user, that the school is inactive.

More about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware

---

Updated:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard $auth
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure                 $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->schools()->status == 0) {
            return response('School is inactive!', 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And add the newly created middleware to the *App\Http* **Kernel.php** class.

Add the following line to the variable **$routeMiddleWare**:

```
'auth'                => \TIM\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
```

Now the last thing to do is to add the **'auth'** key to the *Route group*.

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['auth'],
], function () {
// your routes
}
```

Comment: How can I do that sir. Im not really familiar about middlewares and how to implement them. Should I write a query there?

Comment: Hello @Vince. Look at the updated answer, I will give you a lead on how to archieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You could override the [`attemptLogin`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e04a7ffba8b80b934506783a7d0a161dd52eb2ef/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L79) function to also check for this field.

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    //
    // Query the school status here and return false if status === 0.
    //

    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
}
```

Comment: can I use raw sql queries here sir?

Comment: Yes you can. You will have to query on the users email address though, as you do not yet have the id of the user.

Comment: `select users.email, users.password 
from users
join schools on users.school_id = schools.id
where schools.status = 0;`

is this the correct query sir?

Answer (score 1):

use join query. just add school_id in users table. for example

```
self::where('users.school_id', $id)->where('schools.status',0)
```

Comment: where should I insert this query sir?

Comment: in my migration for users sir? what should i do next? do i have to write a function in the logincontroller?

Comment: all query should always in  model not in controller. first just add migration file then add school_id in users table

Comment: then create a query

Comment: where should i put my query sir? `self::where('users.school_id', $id)->where('schools.status',0)`